# IOError happened while use requests-html to render a javascript page

Tags: javascript, python, request, render

I was trying to use the new liberary request-html.
But when i use the render() function to parse a javascript page, it always pop up with the notes as below:

> Error in atexit._run_exitfuncs: Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pyppeteer\launcher.py", line 201,
>   in killChrome
>       self._cleanup_tmp_user_data_dir()   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pyppeteer\launcher.py", line 130,
>   in _cleanup_tmp_user_data_dir
>       raise IOError('Unable to remove Temporary User Data') OSError: Unable to remove Temporary User Data

I tried to solve the problems, but it seems that there is no solution right now. So i kind of hope someone here can help me.

PS: it seems that i can not post it with the tag:requests-html, i do not have enought repution. So, very sorry for that.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue, but it seems to have disappeared after my second run.  If it keeps happening, perhaps try closing the `request` and/or `session` after you're done:

```
session = HTMLSession()
req = session.get(url)

# do something

req.close()
session.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by switch to the administrator mode.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the connection.py file

pyppeteer/connection.py

@@ -41,7 +41,7 @@ def **init**(self, url: str, loop: asyncio.AbstractEventLoop,

```
    self.connection: CDPSession
    self._connected = False
    self._ws = websockets.client.connect(
        self._url, max_size=None, loop=self._loop)
        self._url, max_size=None, loop=self._loop, ping_interval=None, ping_timeout=None)
    self._recv_fut = self._loop.create_task(self._recv_loop())
    self._closeCallback: Optional[Callable[[], None]] = None
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed mine by adding:
PYPPETEER_HOME to environment variables on my PC, and the variable value to a folder on my PC, ie; 'C:\tool'

variable name: PYPPETEER_HOME,

variable value: C:\tool

and I had to restart my system.